# Why isn't the container div taking full height?

Tags: html, css, height

Here's my code. Can someone please help me understand why isn't my container div taking it's full height ?

I can only "fix" the problem by giving a fixed height, but I want it to take full height no matter how much content there is in it. It seems that something collapse, it won't expand and my footer keeps coming up.

Sorry if it is not clear and thank you for your answers.

```css
/************* GLOBAL ***************/
    
    * {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #e6ccff;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        height: 100vh;
        position:absolute;
    }
    
    .containerHead{
        width: 80%;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    }
    
    .clr{
        clear: both;
    }
    
    
    /************* HEADER *************/
    
    
    header{
        /*background-color: #528;
        height: 70px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px 7px #417 inset;*/
        height: 70px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
    
    
    .logo1 {
        padding: 5px 10px 0 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .logo1 img{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    
    .logo2 {
        padding: 5px 10px 0 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .logo2 img{
        display: inine-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 28px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
    
    .navbar ul{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 50px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
    .navbar ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
    
    .navbar ul li a{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
    
    .nav-item1 :after{
        content:"";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px auto 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-item1 :hover:after{
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-item2 :after{
        content:"";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px auto 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-item2 :hover:after{
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-item3 :after{
        content:"";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px auto 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-item3 :hover:after{
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-item4 :after{
        content:"";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px auto 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-item4 :hover:after{
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .nav-item5 :after{
        content:"";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin: 3px auto 0;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .nav-item5 :hover:after{
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 35);
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /*************** BANNER *****************/
    
    .banner{
        width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
        background-image: url('basket.jpeg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        border-bottom: 5px outset #528;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .cali {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url('cali.png');
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 10;
        transform: rotateZ(30deg);
    }
    
    /*************** CONTENT ****************/
    
    .container{
        width: 80%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        padding: 30px 30px 0;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        clear:both;
        background-color: #FFF;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    
    .title{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 380px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .box1 {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: space-between;
    }
    
    /******************* FOOTER ***************/
    
    footer{
        background-color: #528;
        height: 70px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px 7px #417 inset;
    }
```

```html
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="fr">
         <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>California Purple Eagles</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="eagle.png">
    </head>
    
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="containerHead">
                    <span class="logo1"><img src="eagle.png" alt=""></span>
                    <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item2"><a href="#titleteam">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item3"><a href="#">Match Schedule</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item4"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <span class="logo2"><img src="eagle.png" alt=""></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </header>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="cali">
            <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title" id="titleteam">
                <img src="ourTeam.png" alt="" class="team">
            </div>
            <div class="box1">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
                
            </div>
        </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In the example you've given the `.container` element does take up 100% of the viewport's height

Answer (score 1):

could you try this? Adding display flex and making the padding to 0 normally helps me.

```
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    clear:both;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first but I didn't work out. I tried to think it differently and find ways to fix it but i failed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you want your `.container` element to expand with its content, remove the positioning of the content. In your case, remove the `position: relative;` from `.box1` and also remove `height: 100vh;` and `min-height: 100vh;` from `.container` so it can calculate its height itself.

Comment: I know it looks kind of messy and there's probably a lot of useless code. I'm just beginning to learn and I don't get all the notions yet. Thanks for helping ! In fact I'd just like my container div to take all it's height to the footer, no matter how muck content there's in it. I tried what you said, but unfortunately I didn't fix the problem. If I put too many elements in the box, it goes off everything. Plus theres a space between the container and the footer that I can't get rid off

Comment: Well, the space between the container and the footer is defined by `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` in your code. If you get rid of it, you get rid of the space.